# Translate a MySql query in a Laravel query builder

Tags: mysql, laravel, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

```
SELECT apartment_id, COUNT(created_at) AS n_view,
DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d') as day_view
FROM views
WHERE apartment_id=36 GROUP BY day_view
ORDER BY COUNT(created_at) DESC
```

how can I Translate this  MySql query in a Laravel query builder ?

Comment: [Convert Your SQL to Laravel Builder with Orator](https://laravel-news.com/convert-sql-laravel-builder-orator)

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: @folipso what exactly doesn't work? Are you getting any errors? Not the expected result?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Laravel docs on [query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries) and see the examples, you can easily convert your SQL to query builder:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

DB::table('views')
    ->selectRaw("apartment_id, COUNT(created_at) AS n_view, DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d') as day_view")
    ->where('apartment_id', '=', 36)
    ->groupBy('day_view')
    ->orderByRaw('COUNT(created_at) DESC')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

> > You can do like that   use App\Views;     use DB;

```
Views::select('apartment_id', DB::raw("COUNT(created_at) as n_view") ,DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d') as day_view"))->where('apartment_id' ,36)->orderBy('n_view', 'desc')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::table('views')
    ->selectRaw("apartment_id, COUNT(created_at) AS n_view, DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d') as day_view")
    ->where("apartment_id", "=", "36")
    ->groupBy('day_view')
    ->orderBy(n_view, "DESC")
    ->get();
```

Comment: After the most recent edit (removing some quotes around `n_view`), this will throw a syntax error. Additionally, please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = $this->views;
$data = $data->select(
    "apartment_id",
    DB::raw("COUNT(created_at) AS n_view"),
    DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d') as day_view")
);
$data = $data->where("apartment_id", 36);
$data = $data->groupBy("day_view");
$data = $data->orderBy("created_at", "desc");
$data = $data->get();
```